# Arraylist with a Table View adapter

Tags: android, list, layout, arraylist, adapter

I have a list of friends(picture,name,msg etc...),
I want the list will look something like this -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qd4qK.jpg

I can't figure it out and i tried to search all over the web.

I tried to make the listview layout look like one of the items,but it gave me an vertical version of this.

I just need to figure out what is  the name of this layout or widget,because i can't find any tutorials or examples online.
I'm sure that someone here did this type of thing,and i will be glad to read a tutorial about this.

Thanks.

Comment: It' a gridLayout you are looking for. Google it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is `GridView`. The purpose of `GridView` is to, per the API Guide, "display items in a two-dimensional, scrollable grid"; by your description, this sounds like what you are trying to achieve. An overview of `GridView`, as well as the API Guide, may be found here: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html

I have also included a link to a tutorial that explains, step-by-step, on how to implement a simple `Activity` that uses `GridView` to create a custom grid-based view, along with images and text: http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-custom-gridview.html